# How do I make an event listener with decorators in Python?

Tags: python, discord, decorator

I want to make an event listener
like this:

```py
@some.event
async def on_ready(some_info):
    print(some_info)

@some.event
async def on_error(err):
    print(err)
```

So for when something is ready, or if a message is received in like WebSockets, using this for Discord since some info is only available for when the Bot is Identified or Ready

I've seen something like:

```py
def add_listener(func, name):
   # ...

def remove_listener(func, name):
   # ...
```

But I don't really know how to use it or create one

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need help with? Is it just writing a decorator that calls `add_listener`? Or do you need to know how to make the listener actually function (which is a much bigger question, and likely depends on a lot more details of your problem space, like what kind of events you have to deal with)?

Comment: I want to make an event listener similar to what "I've seen" if you know what I mean. I'm using it for Discord WebSocket/API btw

Comment: Please edit your question (and the tags) to include the fact that this is for Discord.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple class-based solution I quickly coded:

```py
class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialise a list of listeners
        self.__listeners = []
    
    # Define a getter for the 'on' property which returns the decorator.
    @property
    def on(self):
        # A declorator to run addListener on the input function.
        def wrapper(func):
            self.addListener(func)
            return func
        return wrapper
    
    # Add and remove functions from the list of listeners.
    def addListener(self,func):
        if func in self.__listeners: return
        self.__listeners.append(func)
    
    def removeListener(self,func):
        if func not in self.__listeners: return
        self.__listeners.remove(func)
    
    # Trigger events.
    def trigger(self,args = None):
        # Run all the functions that are saved.
        if args is None:
            args = []
        for func in self.__listeners: func(*args)
```

It allows you to create an `Event` that functions can 'subscribe' to:

```py
evn = Event()

# Some code...

evn.trigger(['arg x','arg y'])
```

The functions can both subscribe to the event with decorators:

```py
@evn.on
def some_function(x,y): pass
```

Or with the `addListener` method:

```py
def some_function(x,y): pass
evn.addListener(some_function)
```

You can also remove listeners:

```py
evn.removeListener(some_function)
```

To create something similar to what you asked for you can do something like this:

```py
# some.py

from event import Event

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Private event variable
        self.__event = Event()
        # Public event variable (decorator)
        self.event = self.__event.on

some = SomeClass()
```

And then use it like so:

```py
# main.py

from some import some

@some.event
async def on_ready(some_info):
    print(some_info)

@some.event
async def on_error(err):
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick example :

```py
################################################################################
# the code for the "framework"
event1_listeners = []
event2_listeners = []

def listen_event1(func):
    event1_listeners.append(func)
    return func

def listen_event2(func):
    event2_listeners.append(func)
    return func

def process_event(event):
    if event["type"] == 1:
        for func in event1_listeners:
            func(event)
    elif event["type"] == 2:
        for func in event2_listeners:
            func(event)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{event['type']=!r}")

################################################################################
# your code
@listen_event1
def handle_event1_v1(event):
    print(f"handle_event1_v1 : {event!r}")

@listen_event1
def handle_event1_v2(event):
    print(f"handle_event1_v2 : {event!r}")

@listen_event2
def handle_event2(event):
    print(f"handle_event2 : {event!r}")

################################################################################
# the events processed by the framework
process_event({"type": 1, "msg": "hello"})
process_event({"type": 2, "msg": "world"})
```

```
handle_event1_v1 : {'type': 1, 'msg': 'hello'}
handle_event1_v2 : {'type': 1, 'msg': 'hello'}
handle_event2 : {'type': 2, 'msg': 'world'}
```

Essentially, the decorators will store the function someplace, and when an event is received, the framework iterates over the functions registered for it.
Removing a listener dynamically is basically just removing the `func` reference from the list.
The decorator in this case is simply "sugar" to not having to do `event1_listeners.append(func)` yourself.